# What's the migration from homebrew/dupes to homebrew/core?

Tags: homebrew

I want to install `screen`, but what should I do next?

```
$ brew search screen
imgur-screenshot                                screen                                          screenfetch                                     screenresolution
caskroom/drivers/casio-screen-receiver          caskroom/cask/screen-blacker                    caskroom/cask/show-my-screen                    caskroom/cask/syphon-virtual-screen

If you meant "screen" specifically:
It was migrated from homebrew/dupes to homebrew/core.
```

Answer (score 6):

`homebrew/dupe` is now deprecated all its formula have been migrated to the main repository (`homebrew/core`). As `screen` is now in `homebrew/core`, you just have to do:

```
brew install screen
```

but if you want you can install other third-party repositories (e.g. `homebrew/science`), called taps in the homebrew terminology, with:

```
brew tap homebrew/science
```

You can then directly installed all formulas in this tap. You can also install a formula from an uninstalled tap with:

```
brew install homebrew/science/<formula>
```

To list all your installed taps:

```
brew tap
```

To remove a tap:

```
brew untap homebrew/science
```