# How to install Composer on macOS?

Tags: php, macos, shell, composer-php

I was trying to install the Composer on my macOS version: `high sierra--> 10.13.4`

but after using the command:

```
sudo php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
```

It created some files and directory but it didn't download the composer.
My terminal displayed following **error:**

> No log handling enabled - using stderr logging
>
> Created directory: /var/db/net-snmp
>
> Created directory: /var/db/net-snmp/mib_indexes`

**How can I resolve this problem?**

Answer (score 69):

**OLD Answer (The Ruby Homebrew installer is now deprecated and has been rewritten in
Bash.):**

First install Brew on your MAC:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

**NEW Answer:**

First install Brew on your MAC:

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

Then install PHP:

```
brew update
brew install php
brew install composer
```

To test installation, run:

```
 $ composer -V
```

Comment: show error: 1. Error: homebrew/dupes was deprecated. This tap is now empty as all its formulae were migrated. 2. Error: homebrew/php was deprecated. This tap is now empty as all its formulae were migrated.

Comment: homebrew/dupes is now part of core - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45124717/whats-the-migration-from-homebrew-dupes-to-homebrew-core same with homebrew/php https://github.com/weprovide/valet-plus/issues/127

Comment: I tried `composer update --ignore-platform-reqs` on top of those command and it worked

Answer (score 1):

1. Install Brew in Mac Terminal

`/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"`

2. Install Composer

`brew install composer`

3. Check Composer

`composer -V`

Comment: Step 3 should be `composer -V` with a capital V.

Answer (score -7):

Download and Install composer using the following curl command in the
terminal:

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

After the installation, you will have composer.phar file in the current
directory and the composer command is available as:

```
 php composer.phar [composer commnad]
```

To make composer available globally, you have to move the
recently downloaded composer.phar to the local user’s bin folder as follows:

```
go to /usr/local/bin folder.
```

You can click  Shift + Command + G to open
the dialog to go to the folder.
Move the recently downloaded composer.phar to the usr/local/bin folder
create an alias using the command

```
alias composer="php      /usr/local/bin/composer.phar"
```

Now, you can access the composer from the terminal simply using the
composer command. That's it.