# Errors installing Composer on macOS (JIT compilation failed)

Tags: php, macos, composer-php, jit, php-7.3

When I run `composer --version` in the macOS terminal, I get the following errors.

> PHP Warning:  preg_match(): JIT compilation failed: no more memory in
> phar:///usr/local/bin/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php
> on line 755
>
> ```
> Warning: preg_match(): JIT compilation failed: no more memory in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php
> ```
>
> on line 755
> PHP Warning:  preg_match(): JIT compilation failed: no more memory in
> phar:///usr/local/bin/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php
> on line 759
>
> ```
> Warning: preg_match(): JIT compilation failed: no more memory in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php
> ```
>
> on line 759
> PHP Warning:  preg_split(): JIT compilation failed: no more memory in
> phar:///usr/local/bin/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php
> on line 654
>
> ```
> Warning: preg_split(): JIT compilation failed: no more memory in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php
> ```
>
> on line 654
> PHP Warning:  preg_split(): JIT compilation failed: no more memory in
> phar:///usr/local/bin/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php
> on line 1091
>
> ```
> Warning: preg_split(): JIT compilation failed: no more memory in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php
> ```
>
> on line 1091
> PHP Warning:  preg_replace(): JIT compilation failed: no more memory in
> phar:///usr/local/bin/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Formatter/OutputFormatter.php
> on line 36
>
> ```
> Warning: preg_replace(): JIT compilation failed: no more memory in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Formatter/OutputFormatter.php
> ```
>
> on line 36
>
> ```
>   [ErrorException]                                          
>   preg_match_all(): JIT compilation failed: no more memory
> ```

Comment: Hello there.  We will need more information to really help you.  First, it isn't clear that you are having a software development problem, which is really the purpose of this site (Stack Overflow, or "SO").  I'll assume your question fits since you're probably attempting PHP development/building with Composer.  Next, we need to know how you're trying to install Composer, which version of PHP you have installed, etc.  Finally, this post might help you:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51656914/how-to-install-composer-on-macos

Comment: I don't have a fix for you but I encountered a similar problem. Downgrade to php 7.2.

Answer (score 144):

This is a known PHP 7.3 [bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=77260), which has already been fixed.

As a temporary workaround, edit your php.ini file (in my case: `vi /usr/local/etc/php/7.3/php.ini`), disable PHP PCRE JIT compilation by changing:

```
;pcre.jit=1
```

to

```
pcre.jit=0
```

Comment: this will disable it completely. to just disable it for composer, see bishop's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/53772696/4233593

Comment: my command line interface gives error that it does not have right to write.

Answer (score 35):

I solved this by disabling the PCRE jit compilation.

I suppose you installed php 7.3 through homebrew.

If so, create a `zzz-myphp.ini` in `/usr/local/etc/php/7.3/conf.d` with the following content:

```
; My php.ini settings
; Fix for PCRE "JIT compilation failed" error
[Pcre]
pcre.jit=0
```

Comment: I did this on the loaded php.ini but PCRE JIT is still enabled.

Answer (score 14):

Other answers suggest disabling PCRE JIT via a configuration file. That works, but caveat: this disables PCRE JIT for *all* engine invocations that use those INI files. You therefore won't be getting JIT improvement for a potentially wider swath of functionality, which may not be desired.

You can disable JIT for `composer` only via:

```
php -d pcre.jit=0 composer.phar ...
```

Answer (score 3):

In PHP 7.1.24 there is no  `'pcre.jit'`  in php.ini file so you have to set 
`memory_limit:128M` (if you increase this).

Answer (score 3):

It work for me by follow steps:

1. Open you Terminal and run php --ini
2. Open file php.ini in the path "Loaded Configuration File: /usr/local/php5/lib/php.ini" https://prnt.sc/p9tspy
3. Find pcre.jit and change ;pcre.jit=1 to pcre.jit=0

Comment: This was a very clear step by step explanation. Thank you.

Comment: But in my file pcre.jit not available what should i need to do ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers.. I solved it by command composer.phar and then export path. Example:

```
$composer.phar
$export PATH=/usr/local/php5/bin:$PATH
$composer.phar --version
```

Comment: Is that explicitly telling composer to simply run on PHP 5.x?

Comment: @Umbrella Exactly. Its setting up a path for execution of composer.

Comment: Downgrading PHP also works, but is quite extreme. Perhaps invoking with `-d pcre.jit=0` or adding same to a configuration file would allow you to continue using version 7 without the trouble.

Comment: What happens when something you try to install via composer has php 7 as a requirement? Not to mention the fact that you're keeping a PHP version on your computer that is officially End-of-life.

Answer (score -1):

I got the same error. I installed MAMP 5.4 on my Mac OS 10.11.6 using PHP 7.3.7 and installed Composer. It seemed to work but as soon as I attempted to install Yii2 or even check the version, it gave me the error...

```
$composer.phar --version
Fatal error: Uncaught ErrorException: preg_match_all(): JIT compilation failed: no more memory in phar:///Users/kristin/Sites/htdocs/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Formatter/OutputFormatter.php:137
```

Increasing the memory_limit in php.ini from 128M to anything did NOT solve the issue and pcre.jit=1 was commented out so turning it off didn't do anything either.

Here is what worked:

I simply changed the export path to the previous version's directory (without actually downgrading in MAMP's preferences) and it worked!

```
$export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.20/bin:$PATH
$composer.phar --version
Composer version 1.9.0 2019-08-02 20:55:32
```

If anyone can explain why this worked, I'd appreciate knowing. Cheers.

Answer (score -1):

This works for me -

```
  alias composer='php -d pcre.jit=0 /usr/local/bin/composer'
```

It's does not require and older version of PHP and is specific to composer. To persist across shell closure edit and add to ~/.bash_profile.