# Uncaught ErrorException: preg_match_all(): JIT compilation failed: no more memory

Tags: macos, composer-php, php-7.3

I just upgraded my PHP on macOS from 7.2 to 7.3 and while trying to run `composer update` on a project of mine, I get the error;

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ErrorException: preg_match_all(): JIT compilation failed: no more memory
```

I've run a few Google searches; it looks like the issue is new, and I couldn't find any working documentation online.

Is this an issue related to PHP 7.3 and Composer? If so, how do I resolve it? Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Some answers here solved it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53690624/errors-installing-composer-on-macos-jit-compilation-failed. But it's a temporary hack. This is a known bug in PHP 7.3

Comment: Seems to be. A workaround is to set `pcre.jit = Off` in your PHP configuration.

Comment: Yes @RyanParman, you are correct, that is a work around and I've done it already and it worked.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Errors Installing Composer on macOS (JIT compilation Failed)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53690624/errors-installing-composer-on-macos-jit-compilation-failed)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If pcre.jit = 0 pcre.jit=0 pcre.jit = Off in php.ini, not worked, try this:

I suppose you installed php 7.3 through homebrew.

If so, create a zzz-myphp.ini in /usr/local/etc/php/7.3/conf.d with the following content:

```
; My php.ini settings
; Fix for PCRE "JIT compilation failed" error
[Pcre]
pcre.jit=0
```

If this also doesn't work, uninstall php7.3 and install 7.2 or 7.1

```
brew uninstall php@7.3
```

Comment: xSavitar, Please accept the answer, if you find it as the best among others.

Comment: "I suppose you installed php 7.3 through homebrew." Why yes, yes I did. Going to follow your advice without even reading the commands! Thanks.

Comment: Good that this answer helped you

Answer (score 8):

**Edit the following file**

/usr/local/etc/php/7.3/php.ini

**Find and change the pcre.jit variable**

pcre.jit=0

**If the issue remains**

Try restarting your computer.

Comment: I'm glad I didn't have to reboot this time.