# Laravel Valet always returns "ErrorException: preg_match(): JIT compilation failed: no more memory"

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-valet, valet

A fresh install of Mac OS and Laravel valet didn't help get rid of the problem. I dug deeper and edited the php.ini files of both PHP 7.2 and 7.3.

edit made on both files was "pecr.jit=1 to pecr.jit=0" still no luck.

I've noticed that the errors appear on querying database. Sequel Pro crashes too when this happens.

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me try it

remove brew and composer
and reinstall them and make these tweaks in php.ini

[Errors Installing Composer on macOS (JIT compilation Failed)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53690624/errors-installing-composer-on-macos-jit-compilation-failed)

Comment: Yeah thanks but. I don’t have that kinda problem anymore after I upgraded High Sierra to Mojave.